# Get Scilab to calculate without printing result

Tags: scilab, silent

This sounds like a silly question, but I really can't find an answer around.

I'm using Scilab to evaluate two methods in terms of performace. However, every time I tell Scilab to calculate anything, it will print the results. Since I'm using large matrices, it spends much more time printing the results than doing the calculations, so I'm having a hard time telling how long is each method actually taking.

Can I get Scilab to compute something without printing the result?

That is, instead of

```
-->B = A'*A
  A  =

    1.    2.    3.  
    2.    4.    6.  
    3.    6.    9.  
-->
```

I'd like it to do

```
-->B = A'*A
-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also simply adding a semicolon works

```
-->B = A'*A;
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the right query. When I searched for 'scilab silent', one of the results (not the first) was this:

http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/mode.html

Function `mode(k)` lets you choose how Scilab will behave in terms of variable display. The following call will temporarily hide results:

```
mode(-1)
```

Whereas this will get you back to the default option:

```
mode(2)
```

The documentation is confusing, though.

```
Please notices that mode does not used at prompt, only in an exec-file or a scilab function.
```

Aside from the awful English, this notice seems to be outdated. This function worked perfectly for me on the prompt.